# How to keep whitespace & indentation with Terser plugin in webpack?

Tags: webpack, terser

How do I build my react app using webpack and skip the part of minimize steps that removes whitespaces. I don't want to turn off minimize but just want to skip whitespace removal. I tried

```
minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        compress: false,
      }),
    ],
```

but it didn't do what I wanted.

Is there an option in terser that I can use to skip whitespace removal?

Answer (score 2):

Oohh, it was a hard catch. Terser has [`beautify` option](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference#output-options) of output. So in Webpack config it looks like this:

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
                mangle: false,
                compress: false,
                output: {
                    beautify: true
                }
            }
        })
    ]
}
```